# Cannot generate access token in Lazada Open Platform in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, e-commerce

I m react native developer, Now i'm integrating the lazada open platform with react native app, through node js. I cannot generate access token.

My code is,
const LazadaAPI = require('lazada-open-platform-sdk')

const aLazadaAPI = new LazadaAPI('118985', 'MXbPesO8hJXZFoQNRBMaJAfQPYHdKgwu ', 'SINGAPORE')

// console.log('aLazadaAPIWithToken', aLazadaAPI.generateAccessToken)

const authCode = '0_118985_zUFFF5x0Wal7NNNRKPQFVjSZ2236' // replace valid authCode here
const params = {
    code: authCode
}
const response = aLazadaAPI
    .generateAccessToken(params)
    .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4)))
    .catch(error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 4)))

getting this error,

```
"type": "ISV",
"code": "IncompleteSignature",
"message": "The request signature does not conform to lazada standards",
"request_id": "0b86d3f015889470213992399"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if your developer profile is active ? You need a developer account before you request APIs. Every developer account needs approval by Lazada Open platform, under which each category would require further approvals. This process takes a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Need to generate from the

`https://auth.lazada.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&force_auth=true&redirect_uri=${app call back url}&client_id=${appkey}`